Wireguard routing in a kubernetes home <-> cloud hybrid setup
I have decided to set up a kubernetes cluster using k3s, with a catch, one of the nodes I am using is one of the "always free" oracle cloud arm servers for a bit of extra punch.
To facilitate, I have set up a wireguard network using my two available home nodes, a raspberry pi 5 and an old macbook pro, both running Ubuntu, they each have a separate wireguard port on my WAN.
Getting a k3s cluster up and running on top of this is an exercise best left for the reader, otherwise this post will get way too long.
Everything is set up and configured using ansible.
Here is my problem; One of the uses for my hybrid cluster is Home Assistant, which means integrating with some of the devices I have at home.
My specific issue is that I want to integrate with an Ikea Hub connected to my home network.
By adding 192.168.1.0/24 to home peers AllowedIPs it seems that the routing from the Oracle cloud node seem to work, but no replies will received since routing on the home LAN doesn't seem to work.
Can I set up something purely using wireguard, or do I need to mess around with the routing table in my home router? (A Netgear Orbi mesh in case it matters).
